# Kill and restart Jenkins task in a job without failure

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to kill and restart the jenkins slave task in a job without a failure? If i do it directly, the job fails because the connection was lost.

I need this to refresh the PATH environment variable after the job changes it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are changing the PATH variable, but all the jenkins subtasks are in their own shell...

so `export PATH=$PATH:/custom/bin` with have a live of only the jenkins task and not the whole job and certainly not future jobs

if you are editing something like: `/etc/bashrc` then just stop that...

you can also source a custom script if you were changing a bunch of stuff at the top of the task, like:

```
source ./some/file/that/exports/path
appDefinedInCustomPATH -s dothings
```

Comment: My job calls a puppet agent, that automatically installs some program then adds them to the PATH. The variable editing works fine, but wont take effect on future jobs until i restart the jenkins task.

Comment: can you source them at the top of your task?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the PATH change globally, you need to check through which file ENV or SYSTEM variables are sourced in your Jenkins service file and edit the same.

Yes you will ofcourse need a Jenkins restart to get new Variables sourced